# On resizing the window views should resize correctly

Tags: cocoa, resize, nswindow

In my application i am adding views to a window and i am setting windows size correctly to fit the views.But when i am trying to resize the windows the views in the window the views are not getting fitted depending on the window size one view gets overlapped with the other one and mismatchings. Can any one help me in this isssue by posting some sample how to do it.
i am new to mac development and got strucked up in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`NSView` has a `setAutoresizingMask:` method where you can specify how the view should resize, when its parent view changes size.

You can set this in code, but it might be easier to use Interface Builder.